# PHPUnit Code Coverage of abstract class implementing an interface

Tags: php, interface, phpunit, abstract-class, code-coverage

I'm currently working on Bitcoin Payment Bundle for Symfony2. You can view it on [my github](https://github.com/wikp/WikpPaymentBitcoinBundle). It is not (yet, I hope) fully test-driven developed but I try to make it as test-covered as possible.

Bundle contains the [`AbstractCommand`](https://github.com/wikp/WikpPaymentBitcoinBundle/blob/master/Bitcoin/Client/Command/AbstractCommand.php)  class that implements the [`CommandInterface`](https://github.com/wikp/WikpPaymentBitcoinBundle/blob/master/Bitcoin/Client/Command/CommandInterface.php) interface. Because it is an abstract class, it doesn't need to implement every of interface's methods. Great.

Next, I have the [`AbstractCommandTest`](https://github.com/wikp/WikpPaymentBitcoinBundle/blob/master/Tests/Bitcoin/Client/Command/AbstractCommandTest.php) test case. It tests that `validateParameters` method works well. Test covers every line of the class. But...when I run test-coverage analysis on my IDE (IntelliJ Idea with PHP Plugin) it shows that coverage is magic 93%. This is doubly strange because no line is marked with red color (I've changed default color scheme, so I see it well ;) ).

Question is: why? 
Is it PHPUnit bug? Or maybe it is class-model construction issue? When I had abstract methods inside AbstractCommand (and no interface) they were also not covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved that issue when looked into the clover coverage file. It shows:

```
<file name="/srv/bundles-src/payment-bitcoin/Bitcoin/Client/Command/AbstractCommand.php">
    <class name="AbstractCommand" namespace="Wikp\Payment\BitcoinBundle\Bitcoin\Client\Command">
      <metrics methods="2" coveredmethods="2" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="13" coveredstatements="13" elements="15" coveredelements="15"/>
    </class>
    <line num="0" type="stmt" count="0"/>
        <!-- coverage data for methods -->
    <line num="36" type="stmt" count="0"/>
    <metrics loc="35" ncloc="35" classes="1" methods="2" coveredmethods="2" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="13" coveredstatements="13" elements="15" coveredelements="15"/>
  </file>
```

When you look at the AbstractCommand file, line 36 is a blank line after the class definition. Removing it causes the coverage to be 100%. I think this is the IntelliJ's/PHPStorm's issue.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, You probably didn't cover the `catch` statement from `validateParameters` method.

Try make your `ParameterBug` argument as mock in order to throw an `\InvalidArgumentException` exception in another test. This should cover what you want (but in order to make it possible you have to change your `validateName` method to protected):

```
$parameterSetMock = $this->getMock('AppropraiteNamespace\ParameterSet', array('validateName'));
$parameterSetMock->expects($this->any())
    ->method('validateName')
    ->will($this->throwException(new \InvalidArgumentException);
```

One more thing:

You don't have use try/catch block in your tests. If you use:

```
 $this->setExpectedException('ExpectedException', 'Expected Message');
```

at the beginning of your test, test will fail if the expected exception won't be thrown.

Comment: I'll check that soon and write about results. Despite of them - thanks for the reply!

I try...catch an exception because I want to check whether Exception's parameters are valid. setExpectedException doesn't allow such check (afaik).

Comment: I've checked that and...no, catch statement, as well as whole AbstractCommand class, was covered. There were no "red lines" in my IDE when I ran it with coverage.

Comment: I don't know if you've changed something since last two days, but I've just cloned your project and run unit test. My coverage shows that AbstractCommand is 100% covered.. PHP 5.4.9, PHPUnit 3.7.1, XDebug 2.2.1

Comment: I didn't change anything because I must suspend work on that for a while. But when I had been creating another bundle, I fell into similar issue - resolution in answer below. Thanks for concerning, @Cyprian.